# Why isn't ByteString converted automatically to FilePath?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, bytestring, overloaded-strings

I'm passing a (strict) `ByteString` to something expecting a `System.IO.FilePath`, which is declared as `type FilePath = String`. I'm also using `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`. I've had conversions in some places happen automatically, but here it does not. What have I got wrong?

```
Main.hs:33:40: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘ByteString’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: FilePath
        Actual type: ByteString
```

Comment: In short, no automatic conversions happen in Haskell at all. All conversions are done explicitly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` pragma only works for *string literals*, like `"a string"`. In that case, Haskell implicitly places a `fromString` before every string literal, so it rewrites a string *literal* as `"a string"` to `fromString "a string"`. This only happens for *literals*.

In Haskell, as far as I know, there are *no* implicit conversions. Conversions between for instance `Int` and `Float` are all explicit.

Furthermore note that the [**`IsString`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) typeclass only has a function `fromString :: String -> a`. So that means it works only from a string to that instance (here `ByteString`), not the other way around.

You can use the [**`unpack :: ByteString -> String`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:unpack) to convert the `ByteString` to a `String`.

Comment: But do note that `unpack` is simply wrong for most encodings. And of course also beware that the meaning of a `FilePath` *also* depends on an encoding setting that's hidden behind the scenes. If you are on Linux, you can avoid a lot of headaches by simply using a file API that uses `ByteString` for the name of its files in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, the `OverloadedStrings` extension doesn't enable magical conversion between different types of data. What it does is that when you write a string literal like `"foo"`, the compiler can treat that literal as not only a `String`, but also as a `ByteString`.

You probably need something like `unpack` to convert `ByteString` to `String`.